# Mongoose Sort() by Populated Field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to sort the notes by a populated field, `username`, but it keeps failing.

When I sort by fields of Note itself, it all works well. Problem only comes when it's a populated field.

```
      sort = new Map([
        ['user.username', sortOrder],
        ['_id', sortOrder],
      ])
```

```
  const notes = await Note.find(match)
    .populate({
      path: 'user',
      select: 'username',
    })
    .limit(limit)
    .skip(skip)
    .sort(Array.from(sort))
```

The result of `notes[i].user.username`, as you can see, it's not in alphabetical order:

> 

```
        Juan
        Juan
        Juan
        Juan
        JJ  
        JJ  
        JJ  
        Juan    
        Juan    
        Juan    
        Juan    
        Juan    
        Juan    
        Juan    
        Juan    
        Juan    
        Juan    
        K   
        K   
        Juan    
        K   
        C   
        K   
        Ja
```

I have tried these, did not work:

```
      sort = new Map([
        ['username', sortOrder],
        ['_id', sortOrder],
      ])
```

```
  const notes = await Note.find()
    .populate({
      path: 'user',
      select: 'username',
    })
    .sort({ username: 1 })
```

```
  const notes = await Note.find()
    .populate({
      path: 'user',
      select: 'username',
    })
    .sort({ 'user.username': 1 })
```

```
  const notes = await Note.find().populate({
    path: 'user',
    select: 'username',
    options: {
      sort: [['username', 'asc']],
    },
  })
```